# Running a Function From An External Class Creates Duplicate in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am attempting to call the `reset` function from outside the current class (this will eventually call the reset on multiple classes) but what I am getting is what seems to be the program running the full class again rather than just the function inside that class.

What is going on?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

class Scores1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self.team1 = 888
        self.team1str = StringVar()
        self.teamA()

    def teamA(self):
        self.team1str.set('%03d' % (self.team1))
        t1 = Label(textvariable=self.team1str, font=("Digiface", 120), fg='#fffd80000', bg='black')
        t1.grid()

    def ScoreA1(self):
        self.team1 = self.team1 + 1
        self.team1str.set('%03d' % (self.team1))

    def Reset(self):
        self.team1 = 0
        self.team1str.set('%03d' % (self.team1))

class Resetter(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)

    def reset(self):
        Scores1().Reset


def main():


    sc1 = Scores1(root)
    sc1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    res = Resetter(root)

    sc1.configure(highlightbackground='white', highlightthickness=2)
    root.configure(background = 'black')

    Button(root, text='Team A +1', command=sc1.ScoreA1).grid(row=1, column=0)
    Button(root, text='ResetInside', command=sc1.Reset).grid(row=2, column=0)
    Button(root, text='ResetOutside', command=res.reset).grid(row=3, column=0)

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why would you not use the `Scores` instance you already have?

Comment: Use `sc1.Reset()` in `Resetter.reset()`.

Comment: I need to reset multiple scores and indicators from different functions all over the board. Some need to be reset independently.

Comment: Bonus question... why doesn't `sc1.configure(highlightbackground='white', highlightthickness=2)` create a border around the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there is a typo in your code:

```
Scores1().Reset
```

creates a new instance of `Scores1` and then returns the method `Reset`. To actually call `Reset`, append `()`.

The next problem is that `Scores1()` creates a new instance. But you want to call `Reset()` on `sc1`. The solution is to pass `sc1` to `Resetter`:

```
class Resetter(Frame):
    def __init__(self, sc1, parent=None, **kw):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, kw)
        self.sc1 = sc1
    ...

    def reset(self):
        self.sc1.Reset()

res = Resetter(sc1, root)
```